# How to install Ubuntu Desktop on XFS or BRTFS using automatic partitioning?

Tags: ext4, btrfs, xfs

Currently, when install Ubuntu Desktop, and by choosing automatic partition for a brand new hard drive, there is no way to select which file system will be used for it.

It auto-selects EXT4 and the installation proceeds!

Is there anyway to tell the installation program to use something different, like XFS or BRTFS instead?

I do not want to go through manual steps to use a different file system than EXT4! Because when in automatica mode, it creates boot partitions (EFI) automatically, or Grub partitions sometimes (non-EFI), it calculates the Swap automatically etc... So, I want "guided partition" but using something different than EXT4 for the root file system, but, how?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a bit of a weird way to do this.

If you want to automatically create the swap EFI boot partitions and bootloader, install with ext4.

Boot back into the installer then you can do something more simple of deleting the ext4 partition create an xfs or btrfs partition format it click next and then the install will just go on.

It will reuse the existing swap partition don't worry about it saying that it will format the swap partition as that is parts of ram it just does not want to use currently.

If it is a fresh install then you do not have any data you will lose this way but do not do this on a partition you have things you want to keep as that data will be lost.

The gist here is use automatic to set all that stuff up then ubiquity will reuse what you already have with manual partitioning and you are just changing one partition and reinstalling twice.